# В чем разница между выражениями "высота от уровня моря" и "высота над уровнем моря"?

Tags: семантика

Есть ли разница между выражениями "высота над уровнем моря" и "высота от уровня моря"? Может, в последнем случае имеется в виду поверхность, от которой берется точка отчета?

Comment: Разница только в том, что понятия "высота **от** уровня моря" не существует.

Comment: Тоже так подумал, но при посещении http://www.ruscorpora.ru/new/search-18century.html увидел массу примеров: Уровень моря соответствует начальным понятиям. Восхождение от уровня моря может занимать месяцы, а его математический аналог (понимание доказательства) ― годы. В обоих случаях ― много промежуточных остановок. (В. А. Успенский. Семь размышлений на темы философии математики. 2002)

Answer (score 2):

Разницы в значениях нет. Но есть стилистическая разница.

*Высота́ над у́ровнем мо́ря* (также, абсолю́тная высота, абсолютная отме́тка, альтиту́да) — одна координата в трёхмерном геопространстве (две другие — широта и долгота), показывающая, на каком уровне относительно принятого за ноль уровня моря находится тот или иной объект.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Высота_над_уровнем_моря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F)
*Высота над уровнем моря* — это **научный термин**.

Второй вариант имеет оттенок просторечия. Его целесообразно применять при глаголах:
*Давайте высоту вычислим от (чего?) уровня моря.* || Можно ведь также вычислять от поверхности, на которой находится сам измеряемый объект.

С предлогом "над" — просто факт высоты объекта; "от" — указывает на *отсчитывая от*.

Comment: Oleed,думал, вы новичок. Но судя по этому ответу, вы давно здесь. Под каким ником вы раньше были? Что-то не припомню вас.

Comment: Это мой единственный ник. Не менял его.

Comment: Странно... Ответ ваш помню, а ник нет.