# Помогите с грамотной формулировкой предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Можно ли написать в предложении "50 метров от уровня реки Волги", или принципиальна формулировка "50 метров над уровнем реки Волги"? Возможно ли использование первого варианта?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457024

Comment: Gandhi, смотрите «Поиск по сайту»: он красивый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текстах используются оба выражения:

Высота их **над нынешнем уровнем рек** колеблется от 1 — 2 до 30 м.
Леонид Кондрашев, Археология Москвы: древние и современные черты московской жизни, 2018

К наступлению темноты, абсолютно измученные, мы поднялись приблизительно на 50 метров **от уровня реки**, с которой стартовали.Михаил Александр, Шесть экспедиций

[Предложения со словосочетанием «уровень реки»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Правильным будет вот такой вариант: "На 50 метров выше уровня реки Волги."

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!